# AutoFixture: how to create polymorphic objects with ISpecimenBuilder

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am a little at a loss as to how to code this better. The use of reflection to obtain the `Create<T>` on the specimen context is terrible. Sadly `CreateAnonymous` is deprecated... So I can't think of a better way.

`IX` is an interface, and the specimen builder is creating random instances of concrete classes implementing `IX` for testing purposes.

```
/// <summary>
/// A specimen builder that creates random X messages.
/// </summary>
public class XMessageBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    // for brevity assume this has types implementing IX
    private readonly Type[] types;
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    // THERE MUST BE A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS?
    // CreateAnonymous is deprecated :-(
    public IX CreateSampleMessage(ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var rm = this.types.ElementAt(this.random.Next(0, this.types.Length));
        var method = typeof(SpecimenFactory).GetMethod("Create", new[] { typeof(ISpecimenContext) });
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(rm);
        var instance = generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { context });
        return (IX)instance;
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var parameter = request as ParameterInfo;
        if (parameter == null)
            return new NoSpecimen();

        if (parameter.ParameterType == typeof(IX))
            return this.CreateSampleMessage(context);

        if (parameter.ParameterType == typeof(IX[]))
        {
            var array = new IX[10];
            for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
                array[index] = this.CreateSampleMessage(context);
            return array;
        }

        return new NoSpecimen();
    }
```

Comment: What's terrible about the use of reflection?

Comment: It's not maintainable. If the underlying method changes in any way the test will fail. Hence the test is brittle. Brittle tests are very bad. At least this way a compiler error will result if the API changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
public IX CreateSampleMessage(ISpecimenContext context)
{
    var rm = this.types.ElementAt(this.random.Next(0, this.types.Length));
    return (IX)context.Resolve(rm);
}
```

(I haven't tried to compile and run a repro, though, so I may have made an error somewhere.)

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct pattern. I think my test should run through every possible message rather than random subsets, but that's another debate.

Comment: I couldn't say. That depends on what you're trying to do.